# Aligning two divs with image and text for all devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "img">
    <img src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danieledesantis/playstation-flat/512/playstation-cross-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class = "text">
    <h1>
      Click to close your window.
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.img {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.text {
  width: 70%:
  float: right;
}
```

I want to vertically align the text div with the img div. I want to keep flexible height so I cant use

> display: table and display: table-cell;

I tried playing with padding-top on text but i couldn't get it right for all the devices.

How can I align the text div with the img div so that text always sits in the middle of the image?

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/whqL4fot/1/

Comment: please add desired output.[ output image is best]

Comment: As a developer to a developer, `class = "container"` please... `class="container"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Is this the new norm ? Can you point me to a page where I can read more about it?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan there is no "norm" per-se, it's personal preference - but I do agree with RokoC that without spaces is prettier ( visually )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using Flexbox :)

```
.container {
    -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Updated jsfiddle
( https://jsfiddle.net/whqL4fot/2/ )